# Java - SMTP Transporter requires SocketOutputStream to be open indefinitely

Tags: java, smtp, jakarta-mail

During a refactoring job, I discovered that if I close my outputstream using "try-with-resources" - I always get a `MessagingException` from java's SMTPTransport. It always complains that the socket was closed.

The code which I identified to have the problems is this:

```
try (LineOutputStream los = new LineOutputStream(os);) {
    los.writeln(signatureHeaderLine);
    Enumeration hdrLines = getNonMatchingHeaderLines(ignoreList);
    while (hdrLines.hasMoreElements()) {
        String notIgnoredLine = (String) hdrLines.nextElement();
        los.writeln(notIgnoredLine);
    }

    los.writeln();
    // Send signed mail to waiting DATA command
    os.write(osBody.toByteArray());
    os.flush();
} catch (MessagingException me) {
    // Deal with it
} catch (Exception e) {
    // Deal with it
}
```

The code above is part of an override of `MimeMessage.writeTo(OutputStream, String[])` And the issue comes when `issueSendCommand' and 'sendCommand' is eventually called from [SMTPTransport](http://kickjava.com/src/com/sun/mail/smtp/SMTPTransport.java.htm).

So does this mean my sockets should remain open all the time? I know from non-technical viewpoint, it doesn't feel right to close the socket since I will be writing messages through it. But I was trying to understand whether this would cause memory leak by any chance in the future.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem comes because you are using the OutputStream `os` outside the `try-with-resource` statement.

The `try-with-resource` statement ensures that all initialized `AutoClosable` resources will be closed after execution of the `try` block. At the moment `com.sun.mail.util.LineOutputStream` is closed, also the `OutputStream` `os` (passed to its constructor) will be closed. Any access to `os` after the `try-with-resource` statement acts on a already closed `OutputStream`.

**edit** There is an exception, when the `OutputStream` has a `close()` method without an effect. Which is the case for example for the `ByteArrayOutputStream`.

> Closing a ByteArrayOutputStream has no effect. The methods in this class can be called after the stream has been closed without generating an IOException.

a snippet to demonstrate

```
private static void demoMethod(OutputStream os) throws IOException {
    try (LineOutputStream los = new LineOutputStream(os)) {
        los.writeln("signatureHeaderLine");
        los.writeln();
        os.write("foo".getBytes());
        System.out.println("within try-block");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    os.write("bar".getBytes());
    System.out.println("after try-block");
}
```

calling the method `demoMethod` with a `ByteArrayOutputStream`

```
ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
demoMethod(os);
```

gives the output

```
within try-block
after try-block
```

So the `ByteArrayOutputStream` can be used even after calling `close()` on it (which is implicitly called by the LineOutputStream.close() invoked by try-with-resource code).

Doing the same with a `FileOutputStream`

```
FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("/tmp/dummy.out");
demoMethod(os);
```

throws an exception, because the `FileOutputStream` has been close at the end of the `try-with-resource` statement.

```
within try-block
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Stream Closed
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:342)
    at Main.demoMethod(Main.java:24)
    at Main.main(Main.java:12)
```

Comment: The SocketOutputStream needs to remain open so that SMTP commands can be written after the message content is written.  The Transport object needs to be managed as a resource and closed when it is no longer needed, that will cause the underlying SocketOutputStream to be closed.

Comment: @BillShannon It might depend on the implementation of the `OutputStream` in your code. Maybe adding a snippet which reveals all the necessary information would be helpful. I added a snippet for clarity.

Comment: Yes, but if your code is passed an OutputStream, it generally should not make any assumptions about whether the close method has an effect or not.  And in particular the MimeMessage.writeTo method mentioned in the original post can't make any such assumption.

Comment: @BillShannon I agree with the first part, the code should assume the behaviour as specified in [Outputstream.close()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#close()). As an `OutputStream` is passed to your method you should not close it. If I right understand, that's what lead to your problem. Checking the source of [MimeMessage.writeTo](https://github.com/javaee/javamail/blob/master/mail/src/main/java/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.java#L1907) you see that the `LineOutputStream` is not closed inside.